# Unable to remove association which is read only

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 3 tables

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :accessories
   has_many :product_attribute_categories, through: :accessories, dependent: :destroy
end 

class Accessory < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :product_attribute_category
end


class ProductAttributeCategory < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :accessories, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :products, through: :accessories
  has_many :product_attributes, dependent: :destroy
```

now when I try to delete a ProductAttributeCategory, I want all the `accessories` that it is associated with to be deleted. So it wont return any errors.

However it returns `Accessory is marked as readonly`. So I'm wondering if what I'm doing is not optimal and what I should do instead.

Comment: has_many :product_attribute_categories, through: :accessories, dependent: :destroy in the Product model looks suspect. Rails usually destroys the 'link' table of an association rather than the association itself. In this case, dependent: :destroy should be on has_many :accessories.